# How to use phpThumb with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, thumbnails, phpthumb

Sure, [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) can be installed using [composer](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/phpThumb/blob/master/composer.json#L2). But what's next? Am I supposed to store `phpThumb`'s config at `vendor/james-heinrich/phpthumb/phpThumb.config.php`? What exactly should I do? It's not documented.

Comment: Can you say something out loud, not just downvoting or voting for close?

Comment: Off-topic according to item #4 in the help center http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also, there is a composer package for that.  If you look at the `composer.json` in the package it will tell you the package name: `james-heinrich/phpthumb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to solve this I came up with [a composer package](https://github.com/x-yuri/phpthumb-laravel). It's pretty hackish, so if you've got ideas, you're welcome.

Using OO interface doesn't seem like an option. First, [the readme](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/docs/phpthumb.readme.txt) says:

> #### Calling as an object (not using phpThumb.php):
>
> NOTE: most people don't need to and should not do this. If you just want to
>   display resized images, please just use phpThumb.php, not the object mode.
>   To render output to one (or more) files instead of the browser, you should
>   skip phpThumb.php and instantiate your own object. Please take a look at
>   /demo/phpThumb.demo.object.php for details.
>
> Note: phpThumb.php is where the caching code is located, if you instantiate
>     your own phpThumb() object that code is bypassed and it's up to you to
>     handle the reading and writing of cached files.

And it doesn't solve the issue with config.